# Will std::list::back() produce core dump?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

Imagine that there are lots of threads and every thread will do one of three below operation:

```
auto a = list.back(); // without mutex protection
list.pop_back();      // with mutex protection, guarantee list is not empty
list.push_front();    // with mutex protection
```

It is pretty sure that operation 1) will get unpredictable value.
Will operation 1) cause core dump?

PS: Elements of list is a struct containing a shared_ptr and a integer. I only want to get the value of integer and I can handle the unexpected value sometimes. What I want is never find core dump.

I tried call list.back() first and then pop_back()
or
call list.back() when list is empty().

All tries cannot produce core dump.

Comment: Unrelated: I see too many people misnoming "Segmentation fault" with "core dump". Core dumped is what have been done after triggering a segmentation fault error. It is not an error, segmentation fault is.

Comment: The better question to ask: "regardless of core dumps, is this behavior actually meaningful?" Reading `list.back()` after another thread has popped the last element is a use-after-free and may very well crash if you try using a `shared_ptr` that is in the process of being deleted.

Comment: _"...All tries cannot produce core dump...."_ Undefined Behaviour is undefined.  A [data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races) is Undefined Behaviour. Expecting anything when the code has Undefined Behaviour is wishful thinking.

Comment: If at least one thread modify the list, then you must protect (with a mutex) every access to the list, no matter if you read or write. You probably won't get an error but it is undefined behaviour, you can't guarantee what is returned by `list.back();`

Comment: @Fareanor Even the segmentation fault isn't the error. It's a potential *consequence* of an invalid memory access that happens to go to an unmapped or otherwise protected page. Not causing a segmentation fault doesn't mean the code is correct.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I completely agree with that

Answer (score -1):

It is **guaranteed** that operation 1 causes **Undefined Behavior**. Possible forms of Undefined Behavior include segfaults and/or core dumps, but also deleting every file on your hard disk.

What is **not guaranteed** is the exact form of Undefined Behavior you get. This can even vary from run to run. (Assuming of course that you get the chance of running your program again, before your harddisk is erased).

If you can live with an "unpredictable" value, and want less overhead then a mutex, then there's `std::atomic<>` with `memory_order_relaxed`. But that's mostly useful for a single value, not for a complex datastructure like `std::list`.

In short: lock the mutex on *every* list operation.